# Highcharts - verticalAlign on dataLabels not working on line graph

Tags: highcharts, visualization

I have a Highcharts line graph and I'm considering adding dataLabels to each point. According to the [API documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.dataLabels.verticalAlign), you can change the vertical placement via verticalAlign, but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried editing the [jsfiddle of the basic line](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-labels/) graph to include this:

```
 plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
```

While the dataLabels are enabled, the vertical position doesn't change regardless of what I put for the verticalAlign value. Anyone had this issue with line graphs?

Comment: Works for me.  'bottom' puts them above the points, 'top' puts them below and 'middle' writes them through the points.  Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/h2zgG/

Comment: As Mark posted it is invert, but I reported it as bug for our devs here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1554

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sebastian pointed out in the comment above, verticalAlign does seem to work but it's inverted. Per the head Highcharts developer, this is expected behavior and won't change (includes detailed explanation): https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1554

Comment: Doesn't seem much logical to me. Definitely not uderstadable from official documentation. This important information should be there. It only says: "The vertical alignment of a data label. Can be one of top, middle or bottom. The default value depends on the data, for instance in a column chart, the label is above positive values and below negative values."